# How to get executed code line no. or code itself on frontend using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

How can i find which code was run on particular element?

E.g. if html element has button

```
<input id="x" type="text" value="somevalue">`
```

and if the code was

```
$("#x").val("newval");
```

how can I get that `$("#x").val("newval");` was being run on input of id `x` after the page has been loaded on front end of browser. Is there any way to tell which line no of javascript was executed to change the value or the exact code that was being run?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve.  Can you simplify it for us?

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools you could search for the selector `#x` and see what code references it.  Though that's not necessarily a guarantee, since they could be using `getElementById` or could be selecting the element by some other means, or could be manipulating it through an ancestor element, etc., etc.  Reverse-engineering someone else's code is no trivial exercise.  Taking a step back... What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it in code. But you can set a modification breakpoint in Developer Tools. It will stop when the value is changed, and then you can see what code was doing it in the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry seems bit tough let me clarify . Like for a website there can be lot of files containing lot of jquery code and its very hard to see which line of code might be changing the value of input type of any button so this button for example above has value somevalue at initial load but its being changed by the jquery code $("#x").val("newval"); that might be on any of jquery files so can we see on frontend which code has exactly being run on input of id x  . So we can easily see on which file or line no the code was or easier to search what exact code was being run .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can monkey patch the val function in jQuery, and use Error object to get the stack trace:

```js
((val) => {
    $.fn.val = function(value, ...args) {
        if (this.is('#x')) {
            console.log({value})
            console.log(new Error().stack);
        }
        return val.apply(this, [value, ...args]);
    }
})($.fn.val);
```

When you call:

```js
$("#x").val("newval");
```

the line of the code that was executed will be second in the stack trace:

Check this demo:

```js
((val) => {
    $.fn.val = function(value, ...args) {
        if (this.is('#x')) {
            console.log({value});
            console.log(new Error().stack);
        }
        return val.apply(this, [value, ...args]);
    }
})($.fn.val);

function handle() {
    $("#x").val("newval");
}

$('#y').click(handle);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="x" type="text" value="somevalue"/>
<button id="y">change</button>
```

If you run the code you will get a stack trace like this:

```
Error
    at $.fn.val (https://stacksnippets.net/js:18:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.handle (https://stacksnippets.net/js:25:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:41772)
    at y.handle (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:39791)
```

And your line is:

> at HTMLButtonElement.handle (https://stacksnippets.net/js:25:13)

the number 25 is your line number counted from 0. You can use Regular expressions to extract the number:

```js
((val) => {
    $.fn.val = function(value, ...args) {
        if (this.is('#x')) {
            const { stack, filename } = new Error();
            console.log(stack);
            const line_number = get_line_number(stack);
            console.log({
              value,
              line_number
            });
            // Here you can try to fetch the filename
            // and get the line in the source code
            // but you need to check if the filename exists
            // and if line_number is not undefined
        }
        return val.apply(this, [value, ...args]);
    }
})($.fn.val);

function get_line_number(stack) {
  const m = stack.match(/\$\.fn\.val.*\n.*:([0-9]+):[0-9]+\)/m);
  if (m) {
    return m[1];
  }
}

$('#y').click(function handle() {
    $("#x").val("newval");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="x" type="text" value="somevalue"/>
<button id="y">change</button>
```

The problem with this code is that (at least Google Chrome) doesn't show the proper line number in the stack trace. But maybe it's just Stack Snippet that uses an inline Script tag. I used this approach to render stack trace when you can click on the line to get the source in jQuery Terminal:

[image: jQuery Terminal with an error]

see demo: https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/BaGWRJy

And the code that renders the error looks like this:

```js
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// :: Display line code in the file if line numbers are present
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
function print_line(url_spec, cols) {
    var re = /(.*):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)$/;
    // google chrome have line and column after filename
    var m = url_spec.match(re);
    if (m) {
        // TODO: do we need to call pause/resume or return promise?
        self.pause(settings.softPause);
        $.get(m[1], function(response) {
            var file = m[1];
            var code = response.split('\n');
            var n = +m[2] - 1;
            var start = n > 2 ? n - 2 : 0;
            var lines = code.slice(start, n + 3).map(function(line, i) {
                var prefix = '[' + (n + i - 1) + ']: ';
                var limit = cols - prefix.length - 4;
                if (line.length > limit) {
                    line = line.substring(0, limit) + '...';
                }
                if (n > 2 ? i === 2 : i === n) {
                    line = '[[;#f00;]' +
                        $.terminal.escape_brackets(line) + ']';
                }
                return prefix + line;
            }).filter(Boolean).join('\n');
            if (lines.length) {
                self.echo('[[b;white;]' + file + ']');
                self.echo(lines).resume();
            }
        }, 'text');
    }
}
```

You can also see the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/master/js/jquery.terminal-src.js#L7647C1-L7680C10).